# Organise dropdown options into different Excel Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

So a multifaceted problem:

I have created a training request sheet that I have now been asked to split into different excel sheets for different requests

Using the VBA below I am able to move 1 option to a new sheet but when try to add an additional condition, by simply reproducing the same vba for each variable, it fails.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("E:E")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    If Target = "Head and Neck" Then
        Target.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("HN").Cells(Sheets("HN").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Rows(Target.Row).Delete
    End If
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Also when the automation works it is deleting the cells that are assigned with the dropdown menu. Is there anyway to create to maintain the dropdown whilst deleting the input data?

Many Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? How did you add additional conditions? Please include that in your question. Also it is a bit unclear what your question is. If you don't wan't the row to be deleted than remove the line that delets it `Rows(Target.Row).Delete`.

Comment: Just FYI as a user entering data I'd find it pretty disconcerting to have my entered data disappearing before my eyes...   And just because I've changed a value in ColE doesn't mean I'm finished with my entry.   I would maybe suggest trying some thing a little less "automated" - have the user click a button when they're done with their entries.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Initially all data input will be done by myself its the subsequent tables that are produced that will be used by others. In the future this may change.